# Is there a way to display a different graph only when you select a graph variable?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

first, i wanna show only pie graph.
and only if i select one of the pie graph fragments, I'd like to show the corresponding bar graph value.

Is there a way?

[image]

Comment: As far as im aware you cant have such triggers (onClick on object). The only way i can think of is to have calculation condition based on the selected values. So for example if only one Month is selected - calculate the bar chart. If more than one is selected (or no selection in the field) then show some message. If this is ok then i can provide an example

Comment: oh..I'd appreciate it if you could.

Answer (score 1):

**In QlikView**

1. Open the chart preferences
2. Add the calculation condition `= GetSelectedCount(FieldName) = 1` (More about [GetSelectedCount](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2021/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/ChartFunctions/FieldFunctions/getselectedcount.htm) function)

[image: Calculation condition]

3. Open `Error Messages`

[image: Error messages button]

4. Select `Calculation condition unfulfilled`

[image: Standard messages]

5. Enter the message. It can be a plain text or expression/calculation

[image: Message]

Now if nothing is selected in `Director` field (or more than one value is selected) the error message will be shown

[image: Before]

If only one value is selected then the chart will be calculated

[image: After]

**In Qlik Sense**

In the chart properties expand `Data handling` and add the condition in `Calculation condition` and the message in `Displayed message` (as in QV the message can be plain text or calculation)
[image: Data handling]

Nothing is selected (or more than one is selected) and the message is shown

[image: Before]

Only one value is selected and the chart is calculated

[image: After]